# Stop link from loading

Tags: javascript

I have been trying for a few hours now and decided to finally post here. I have been trying so many methods to get my links to stop with preventDefault, this way I can load in content async.

All my links that i have tried that are apart of the template (like in the header) work perfectly, but any of the links brought in through an async view (and generated via js) completely skip over this snippet of code. I wanted to track anything that has a className "router" and stop the default action and run the function navigate instead.

```
var routeclicked = document.getElementsByClassName('router');
    for(let i = 0; i < routeclicked.length; i++) {
      routeclicked[i].addEventListener("click", e => {
        console.log("Router is: " + routeclicked[i]);
        e.preventDefault();
        router = routeclicked[i].pathname;
        console.log("Router 2 is: " + router);
        navigate();
      });
    }
```

Comment: This wouldn't be sufficient for me to help you with your problem. What is `routeclicked`? What is the element set of elements with class name "router". What is `navigate`? Rest assured it is sufficient to call `preventDefault` on the event provided by a "click" event handler, in order to prevent default behavior -- following a hyperlink. So if it does not work for you, your event handler isn't getting invoked for the expected element(s) or something else is amiss. Please provide minimal hypertext that loads a script that includes the above.

Comment: Routeclick is just the var declared, but it is always an <a> tag. The function navigate can be ignored, since the code doesn't even execute to that point on an asynchronous loaded view

Comment: Then I advise you to test your application with Firefox or Chrome where you can use "Developer Tools" and check that the elements you suspect of not suppressing hyperlink navigation, have the "click" handler attached that calls `preventDefault`, or where there exists an ancestor element with a similar "click" handler attached, that may be processing events from its descendants using event bubbling or capture. That's all there is to it, really -- if `preventDefault` is called on a "click" event, it's the end of the road for link navigation -- unless somewhere something navigates explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a listener to `"body"` or the first non-dynamic parent.
You could go for  `Event.target` and `.closest()`.
Also, don't put functions inside `for` loops, it defies the reusability of functions.

```js
const navigate = (EL) => {
  location = EL.pathname;
}

const navigateHandler = (ev) => {
  const EL = ev.target.closest(".router"); // Self or closest
  if (!EL) return;
  ev.preventDefault();
  navigate(EL);
}

document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", navigateHandler);
```

Comment: Okay I will try this out, can you explain the `EL_router` bit?

Comment: @Matt Sorry for the mistake, I was rationalizing the code variables and forgot to edit.

Comment: Ah thanks, I thought it was something new, will try this out later and report back.

Comment: This works exactly! Thanks so much!! I can't believe the solution was so simple.